# multicolumn lists latex

Tags: latex

Is there a way of making lists in latex using multicol such that the numbering is in this form
1   2
3   4
5   6
instead of
1   4
2   5
3   6

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try the multienum package.

http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multenum/

http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/multenum/multienum.pdf